# Whole dataset generated/saved on colab. RAM error when fed to model.fit but not when using a data generator, why?. What is the best practice?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, large-data

For this DL project, I am generating grayscale "images", which are actually numpys (over 50'000 of around 3000 pixels each). At first, I generated them on my computer and loaded them on my drive which I mounted on colab. I used a data generator to get the saved images/numpys and feed it to model.fit using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator. Using this method was incredibly slow as the dataset needed to be shuffled and so on. As I understand it, colab can be very slow at getting large amount of data on the drive.

Then I switched to generating the images on colab directly and saved it in a big array (nb of images,height image, width image) and still used the generator to feed it to model.fit which worked much much faster. I then tried to remove the data generator as I figured it didn't make sense to keep it as all the data was saved on colab/the notebook and gave the whole data to model.fit but this somehow always gives me  the "Your session crashed after using all available RAM" error (I somehow never get the option to upgrade the memory like I used to).

So I am wondering, why am I getting this error as I don't understand why the data generator would work better. Should I keep using the data generator or is there another way to do it which is more robust/faster or "looks" better ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Keeping your entire data in RAM is not feasible if you have huge data. If you try to load more data than the storage capacity of RAM you will get this error.

Comment: Thank you but what I dont understand is that the data is already in RAM as it is saved in the big numpy array. I guess its when the weights of the neural networks are updated that there is a problem. But why does it matter if its given through a generator or with the whole data? Shouldn't model.fit use it the same way, as I used the same parameters (number steps_per_epochs and so on..). Hope it's more clear